# Revolution slider is inserting a back-ground image url as undefinded causing me an issue

Tags: revolution-slider

This occurs when it renders the bullets -

This is the HTML it is inserting  the class="tp-bullet-image" with a style="background-image: url("undefined")

I searched through the .js files and the .css files and can't find the style or where it is coming from.

Seems to keep the slider from auto sliding - I can't find where this style is coming from.

Thanks, Geoff

Comment: I found the answer - you have to set the tmp variable to a valid class name - if you do not set this it marks it as undefined

Comment: Where did you set this tmp var?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Geoff's response to his own question, the `tmp` key must be added to the `bullets` associative array:

```
 navigation: {
   bullets: {
     enable: true,
     style: 'custom',
     tmp: '',
     ...
   }
 },
```

See the [Slider Revolution Documentation > Navigation Syntax > Bullets](https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/navigation-syntax/#bullets). Note: The `style` key can be set as desired (not necessarily `custom`).